# PostgreSQL, Storing multiple variables in the stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.2

How to store multiple variables from the query in the stored procedure?

For one variable it can be done easily but how to do it if it's more than one for the same query?

```
declare num1 int;
declare num2 int;
select number1 into num1 from table_a where id = 1;

-- This one is not correct
select number1 into num1, number2 into num2 from table_a where id = 1;
```

Is there any simple way to do it without using `cursor variable`?

Comment: I prefer to use `record` variable in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quote from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

> *where target can be a record variable, a row variable, or **a comma-separated list** of simple variables*

So it should be:

```
select number1, number2 
   into num1, num2 
from table_a where id = 1;
```

Alternatively you can use a record variable:

```
declare result_rec record;
...

select number1, number2 
    into result_rec
from table_a where id = 1;
```

Comment: With `record`, it looks better (IMHO) to do `FOR result_rec IN SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id=1 LOOP ... END LOOP`